# Horizontal align of floating elements within a responsive div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an element with structure like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkaN/aeb1qs8j/), but in action it's responsive. So the width is always different and I faced a difficulty to center the LIs when the UL is smaller than default. Here's the code:
[HTML]:

```
<ul>
    <li>Some nice text</li>
    <li>Some nice text</li>
    <li>Some nice text</li>
    <li>Some nice text</li>
    <li>Some nice text</li>
    <li>Some nice text</li>
    <li>Some nice text</li>
    <li>Some nice text</li>
</ul>
```

[CSS]:

```
ul {
width: 400px; /* <-- try to change it - li won't be centered :(*/

    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0 16px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

li {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #AAAAAA;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}
```

The clear question is: how to align horizontally the floating elements in a block with responsive width?

Comment: try this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/csxjq30a/

Comment: What happens if, for example, the final row has fewer elements than the other rows? How do you want those to be aligned?  Also, will the width of `li` be 100px or a % value of the parent width?

Comment: @mary-melody hm, it works in the fiddle, but in the real code it doesn't, can you, please, check [this](http://dev.project-skan.com/1cr_chooser/), I really don't know what's the difference.

Comment: @SkaN Set vertical-align top to `li`s like this - "`.chooser.contents li {vertical-align: top;}`" and remove the `float: left;` from `li` or (`.chooser.contents li`), you don't need to use float left and let me know if it doesn't work for you. :)

Comment: @marc-audet the width is always fixed. the last row doesn't really matter. it would be good, if it behaves like text-align: left, but even if it's centered, it's still fine.

Comment: @mary-melody wow, it works now :D never thought that vertical-align works outside the table context. thanks very much :) you should post it as an answer, so that i can rate you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could align horizontally center `inline-block` elements by giving the parent element `text-align: center;` and add `vertical-align` (e.g. top) to child elements to avoid the vertical positioning issues.

Add `text-align: center;` to the `ul` and add `vertical-align: top;` to the `li` and remove the `float: left;` from `li` tag.

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v5vL5p5n/)

```
ul {
    width: 400px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 0 16px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #AAAAAA;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```